# Why isn't VS Code setting every line to a max of 80 on save?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I installed the Prettier extension and the max line width is set to 80. I also have it set to format on save. When I save the file I'm working on, I see that the comments are still really long widths. The extension should be shortening these to 80 max width, but it's not doing it. Is there another setting I need to use? Or maybe there's a better extension than Prettier? I just want to use whatever formatter that will get rid of the 200+ errors when I try to deploy my typescript cloud functions.

Comment: You should check out the instructions for the plugin before asking SO. You can also click on the prettier statusbar text on the bottom right to see errors in the plugin. Prettier will format comments to 80 chars by default, if it's not doing that, you've misconfigured the plugin, or more likely, you haven't installed prettier locally, as described in the plugin readme.

Comment: @AndyRay there are no errors on the bottom right tab for Prettier. When I installed the plugin from VSCode > Extensions, there was only one installation option and it installed it globally.

Comment: Check your prettier config file (perhaps `.prettierrc`) and set `"printWidth": 80,`. Restart VS Code to see if changes take effect.

Comment: @Justin It looks like I don't have a .prettierrc file. How do I add it and what do I put in there?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat A `prettierrc` file is a config file for prettier. There are a few ways to configure prettier. I'd recommend checking the prettier docs on this one, which explain it quite well: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html Basically you choose a home for your config and then enter in all your custom configurations.

Comment: My mistake, you want [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) (it's what I use). TIL prettier doesn't format comments

Comment: @AndyRay rewrap worked for normal comments, but for comments trailing a line of code it didn't work. Luckily I didn't have many of those so I just moved those to above the line of code. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin making a config file/restarting it seems to have worked for everything except for certain edge cases. For me, it couldn't fix long strings. I had to manually switch those to the multi-line string format.

Answer (score 1):

Prettier doesn't format comments, see https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#comments

I'd recommend turning your comments into [jsdoc-style comments](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html) and line break them yourself.

vscode has a nice feature where adding a line break in a comment makes that new line also a comment.

By the way, I can't comment on your post since I don't have enough reputation lol, but you can create a basic prettier configuration file by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P and typing prettier,
[image: creating a prettier configuration file in vscode]